# How to import Angular Web Component in another Angular App

Tags: angular, web-component

I have one app built with Angular 5.2. I've also built a web component from Angular 8.0. If I'm about to put that web component in a static html I would do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Custom Button Test Page</title>
  <!-- This is the Web Component import -->
  <script src="elements.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<custom-button></custom-button>
</body>

</html>
```

Running this index.html file would have the web component built in. How ever if I apply the same approach to an Angular app (to include it in my Angular 5.2 app), it doesn't work.

If I try importing straight from main index.html, I get the file not found error. If I import it from angular.json scripts, I will get unexpected token error.

How exactly am I supposed to import an Angular web component into existing Angular app?

Comment: You can't use a `8.0` component in a `5.2` app. You'll need to upgrade your angular version. I'm not sure what you mean by "static" html. You can't consume a component without running angular

Comment: @Liam You are wrong there. I’m talking about Angular Elements aka Web Components. I’ve plugged the Angular v7 web component in Angular v4 app in the past and it was working good

Comment: And I am not talking about normal components. It seems that you are not familiar with the concept of web components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to import the script in angular.json / .angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
   "assets/elements.js"
]
```

How ever if you leave it like that, you will still get the errors most likely to multiple zone.js imports - One coming from your Angular App and other one from your Angular Web Components app. The solution is to disable one of those. Logically it would be to disable the one coming from a web component - but it turned out that it doesn't work. You will have to remove the import of zone.js from your main Angular App, and keep it in your web component.

Go to **polyfills.ts** and comment out or remove

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Also don't forget to add **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA** to your AppModule so that Angular knows you will be using outside components.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ... ],
    bootstrap:    [ ... ],
    imports: [ ... ],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

Now you can use your web component anywhere in your application with

```
<custom-button></custom-button>
```

**WARNING:**
This approach will not work if you are running **different versions of webpack** in those two applications

Comment: Were you able to build the project and get it working? For me, the component is working fine if I run the project using ng serve. But I'm unable to see anything (literally nothing) if I try to run the files complied by ng build --prod. As soon as I add in "scripts" in angular.json I'm facing this.

Comment: @UtkarshGupta I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: @user14649759, Sadly no. We moved to use React instead.

Comment: I was able to get it work, If I’ll have time this weekend, I’ll try to do it with latest Angular version.

Comment: @Dino I hope you get a solution, I think it's a webpack problem when you go in prod

Comment: @Dino did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to leave the polyfills.ts file in the main app unchanged and in the web component app :

go to **polyfills.ts** file and comment out

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

in the same file put a check to add the import only if the zone is not present

```
declare var require: any
if (!window['Zone']) {
    require('zone.js/dist/zone'); // Included with Angular CLI.
}
```

If you continue to receive error about the zone in the main application maybe you concatenate the es5 polyfills file.

When building the web component application in the dist folder you get five output files  `runtime.js`, `scripts.js`, `main.js`, `polyfills.js` and `polyfills-es5.js`. Try concatenating the four first and together with the change above you should see your main application working fine with the web component.